# Jack audio suddenly does not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Audio was working perfectly, even jack, I was able to listen to music using headphones or external speakers.

Today I tried to install tuxguitar from its .deb installer and suddenly, the audio through the jack connector does not work.

I am not able to plug either headphones or external speakers. However, audio works perfectly using the internal speaker of my laptop.
I have read several threads but solution at all find it.

Any suggestion please?

Volume Control seems to be working because there is movement on the audio volume bar.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look on: http://askubuntu.com/questions/868467/ubuntu-16-04-front-panel-audio-does-not-work/868468#868468 It is similar to your problem