# Ubuntu 16.04 Front Panel audio does not work

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa

On my desktop running Ubuntu 16.04 I can have audio on the speakers connected n the read but I do not have audio on my headphones.

Further investigation has shown that somehow the front panel audio is muted by default whilst the speakers are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `alsamixer` to the terminal and using left and right arrow keys in to the `Headphones` selection if is muted (shows MM on above) press `M` to unmute and press the up arrow to volume up

Afterwards insert the following command to the terminal:

```
alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state store
```

To store the settings into a file to your home folder. Then in order to restore it every time you login (is the best option I've tried) use this command:

```
echo "alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore" >> ~/.bashrc
```

## Update

Also the source of the problem, in my case is that the Front Panel uses [AC'97](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC%2797) instead of [IntelHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_High_Definition_Audio) one, so setting the appropriate setting into BIOS settings also fixed the problem whithout the need to do the following fix above.

So have a look first whether your motherboards Supports the older [AC'97](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC%2797) format as well alongside with [IntelHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_High_Definition_Audio), especially if you custom-built your desktop computer.