# Front Panel Audio Issue

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have a desktop PC running Ubuntu 16.04 in the living room in which i am facing a strange behavior concerning the front panel audio output.
Yesterday, after noticing i was not having sound coming out of the jack i followed the guidelines in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868467/ubuntu-16-04-front-panel-audio-does-not-work) from which i managed to get fixed in the current session.

Unfortunately, every time i reboot the system, the audio is only produced in back panel while front panel jack is activated only if i open a terminal window (either via launcher or shortcut `ctrl-alt-t`). Soon after i have an open terminal, front audio jack/headphones start working and i have sound.

Checking `alsamixer` parameters in a terminal before logging in an user, every setting appear to be normal and Headphone option is not muted.

Checked shortcuts keys in OS and there are no conflicts with media/sound related tasks.

I don't mind having to open and close a terminal to get my headphones working. The problem is that the PC is used by other people in my house that barely know what a terminal is and it would be a very uncomfortable workaround to explain.

This is such a very odd behavior that i got curious with so i am sharing it with anyone who might might tip the possible silly root cause.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Look at your alsamixer if auto-mute is enabled. It's at right-side. Maybe you have to disable it, to get headphones work from startup. Other option is you do a script with that command within and adding it to your _Session Applications Preferences_.

Comment: In fact, the solution you appointed indicates to store that command at `~/.bashrc`. It indicates that you wil execute that command only when you open a terminal session. Creating a script with that command and attaching as I did above solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script with that command you said at other issue. (I suggest you to store at ~/unmute.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/alsactl --file /home/<user>/.config/asound.state restore
```

So you could do this:

[image]

Comment: Just did this. I don't know why but the script is not running at startup, i am looking into why its not running.
Headphone volume going back to 0 whenever system start. It only works if i run the script in a terminal. Thank you for the quick response. ;)

Comment: Perhaps `alsactl` is not reachable without complete name `/usr/sbin/alsactl` at login startup. I edited my answer. Maybe so it will work without need to open a terminal.

Comment: Ok, just did this. Still volume 0 & muted at startup.  I named my file `.unmute.sh` so it is hidden but i don't think its the cause.

Comment: But the script is executed? Look at /var/log/syslog if it's executed. In a terminal session, type `amixer controls`,  and output the result here, please. If you prefer, put it in your question.

Comment: Done. After entering full  command  path in `Edit Startup Program` it's now working. For some reason `~/` is not accepted (?).
Thank you very much for your patience!